# does "town" and "city" are the same place in this context?

Tags: grammar, meaning, ambiguity, reference

does "town" and "city" are the same place in this context?

i mean. does the "city" refers to the mentioned "town"?

> This drives him to the consideration of whether these things may not
>   be explained as the reflection of the mind of some other living human
>   being. These considerations have been exhausted by every inquirer in
>   turn, for Spiritualists do not accept their creed in one bound, but
>   make the journey step by step, with much timid testing of
>   the path. Judge Edmonds's epitome of his course is but that which many
>   others have followed. He gives the following reasons for negativing
>   this question of other human minds: *Facts were communicated which were
>   unknown then, but afterward found to be true; like this, for instance
>   when I was absent last winter in Central America, my friends in **town**
>   heard of my whereabouts and of the state of my health seven times; and
>   on my return, by comparing their information with the entries in my
>   journal it was found to be invariably correct. So, in my recent visit
>   to the West my whereabouts and my condition were told to a medium in
>   this **city**, while I was travelling on the railroad between Cleveland
>   and Toledo. So thoughts have been uttered on subjects not then in my
>   mind, and utterly at variance with my own notions. This has often
>   happened to me and to others, so as fully to establish the fact that
>   it was not our minds that gave birth to or affected the communication.*

source:http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html _ hos by acd

Comment: The highlighted text appears to be directly quoting Judge Edmonds's words, but *we don't know where he was when he first delivered them* (i.e. - ***this city***). Most likely an *American* city, but feasibly not the location Edmonds thinks of as being "in town" (which for many *Brits* at the time would have meant ***London***, even if he was actually speaking at ***this city of Cambridge***, for example.

Comment: Probably, but we can't tell for sure. Note that [in town](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_town) is an idiom, which may refer to a conurbation of any size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Judge Edmonds writes "this city" he means the city that he is in *right now* (i.e., at the time he was writing the letter or article). Earlier in the passage from the book that you linked, it says, "In a communication addressed 'To the Public,' published in the New York Courier and dated New York, August 1, 1853, Judge Edmonds, a man of high character and clear intellect, gave a convincing account of his own experience."

Therefore, readers in 1853 would have understood "this city" to mean New York City. In the 19th century, when people wrote letters, they would typically identify their location at the top, along with the date. When they wrote "this city" they were referring back to that location. This was also a common practice in newspaper writing at the time.

"My friends in town" is a colloquial expression. He means his local friends, whether they lived in a small town or large city.